# JavaScript error “is not a function”

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try in jsfiddle it's work but if didn't work on my website. Anyone can help me?

```
$("#listReason").on("change",function(){

if($(this).val() == "Hack")
  $("#banlength").val("0");

});
```

Comment: Is JQuery loadinfg properly before you execute this script?

Comment: What exactly is not a function?

Comment: And the full error message is...

Comment: Make sure JQuery.js is loaded, but also you might need to make sure "listReason" is loaded also, by putting this in an onload function i.e. wrapping your code here with $( document ).ready(function() {});

Comment: what error message did you get?

Answer (score 1):

You should post your html, but make sure you reference jquery before this function is called

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
```